# Laravel - DB group by month

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am querying my users to return a list of them, here is an example

```
$user_list = DB::table('users')
            ->select('name','email','created_at')
            ->orderBy('created_at')
            ->get();
```

I am seeing the correct results, but I am trying to split these results up so that they are grouped by month.

Does anybody have some docs I can read or some example code of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is section in the docs, where you can find an information about the `groupBy` method - [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#collection-method)

In your code you can write this():

```
$user_list = User::select('name','email','created_at')
        ->orderBy('created_at')->get();// get User collection
$user_list->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
   return $item->created_at->format('m');
});
```

Comment: It is not recommended to pull the entire list and then perform a group by on the collection. Think of a scenario where the data returned by the Eloquent query is a large dataset. It is always better to handle this operation directly on the database as the query execution on the database is faster and optimized. The answer provided by @MehravishTemkar is more optimized and follows the best practice.

Comment: @Abishek yes i agree your point.But op accepted answer reason might be Mehravish Temkar answer will return one row for each month but the Pavel answer will return all row for each month .

Comment: @JohnLobo, @Pavel's answer will retrieve every row from the User Table as it doesn't have any clauses on the first query that is executed against the DB. It only does an `OrderBy` and retrieves the entire result set from the DB. It them does a GROUP BY on the collection `$user_list`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$user_list = DB::table('users')
            ->select('name','email','created_at')
            ->orderBy('created_at')
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))
            ->get();
```

Comment: @JohnLobo thanks for fixing the bug :) You have earned remarkable reputation in a very short time

Answer (score 0):

```
$groupedUsers = $users->mapToGroups(function ($user, $key) {
    return $user->created_at->month => $user; 
});
```

This may be a little less code than some of the others. They will all work though. Here, you can replace `$users` with `User::all()` if you have your model set up correctly.