# Laravel group by month from created_at column and sum rows multiplied with price is not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to get data from 2 tables where I want to fetch the cost group by month. The 2 tables are

```
spare_stock_history
(spare_id, amount, created_at)
```

and

```
base_inventory
(id, unit_price)
```

I need to get sum of amount*unit_price at each month by using created_at column of stock history.

I have written the following query

```
 StockHistory::
        select("spare_stock_history.created_at")
        ->sum("spare_stock_history.amount*base_inventory.unit_price")
        ->join("base_inventory","base_inventory.id", "=","spare_stock_history.spare_id")
        ->where(["spare_stock_history.transaction_type"=>2])
        ->orderBy('created_at')
        ->groupBy(StockHistory::raw('MONTH(spare_stock_history.created_at)'))
        ->get();
```

But it is giving me following sql error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'spare_stock_history.amount*base_inventory.unit_price' in 'field list' (SQL: select sum(`spare_stock_history`.`amount*base_inventory`.`unit_price`) as aggregate from `spare_stock_history`)
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - DB group by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49335614/laravel-db-group-by-month)

Comment: @Abishek , i have updated the question from your suggestion. Can u please check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DB:raw` to handle raw expressions on your Query Builder.

```
   StockHistory::
select(["spare_stock_history.created_at", DB::raw("SUM(spare_stock_history.amount * base_inventory.unit_price)")])
    ->join("base_inventory", "base_inventory.id", "=", "spare_stock_history.spare_id")
    ->where("spare_stock_history.transaction_type",2)
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(spare_stock_history.created_at), SUM(spare_stock_history.amount * base_inventory.unit_price)'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Getting this error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sanofi.spare_stock_history.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `spare_stock_history`.`created_at`, SUM(spare_stock_history.amount * base_inventory.unit_price) from `spare_stock_history` inner join `base_inventory` on `base_inventory`.`id` = `spare_stock_history`.`spare_id` where `spare_stock_history............`

Comment: @MRahi, I have updated the code. Your MySQL has strict mode enabled, so you have to include all the columns you have on your `SELECT` on your `GROUP BY` as well. If you want to disable this, then you can do so by updating the `strict_mode` on your `database.php` config.

Comment: Still this error: although i have disabled strick mode `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1056 Can't group on 'SUM(spare_stock_history.amount * base_inventory.unit_price)' (SQL: select `spare_stock_history`.`created_at`, SUM(spare_stock_history.amount * base_inventory.unit_price) from `spare_stock_history` inner join `base_inventory` on `base_inventory`.`id` = `spare_stock_history`.`spare_id` where `spare_stock_history`.`transaction_type` = 2 group by MONTH(spare_stock_history.created_at), SUM(spare_stock_history.amount * base_inventory.unit_price) order by `created_at` asc)`

Comment: @MRahi, if you are disabling strict mode, then remove `SUM(spare_stock_history.amount * base_inventory.unit_price)` from your group by function